# How to get class name of parent div of html link from which javascript function is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the class name of the parent div from which a html link calls a javascript function?

In the following code example:

```
<div class="parent-class">
  <a href="javascript:parent(this.parent)">Find parent</a>
</div>

<script>
  function parent(parent) {
    var theValueImLookingFor = (parent.className);
  }
</script>
```

I would like the "theValueImLookingFor" to be "parent-class", but I keep getting "undefined".

I been trying to figure this out for almost an hour, what can I change to make this work? I understand there are more static ways to get this information, but for my specific purpose I really need to identify the div through the javascript function from which it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged this with jQuery, which will be the easiest way to find the details of the parent div. Something like

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <a id="link">Find Parent</a>
</div>

<script>
    $('#link').click(function() {
        alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly when I refer to a class instead of an ID!

Comment: You can use a class or an id if you want, you would just need to update the selector. $('#foo') would select an element with id="foo" $('.bar') would select an element with class="bar"

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid using JavaScript as an href value, and do something like this:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

var doc = document;
function getParentClassName(childNode){
  return childNode.parentNode.className;
}
console.log(getParentClassName(doc.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]));

}
```